# How to make a blacklist configuration for Jersey2?

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, jersey-2.0

**Info :** I have Spring based REST project with Jersey. I use Maven to manage dependencies.

I've been using *Jersey 1.x* for a few months and decided to upgrade my project to *Jersey 2.x*. And also i want to add a blacklist manager to prevent the application from attacks. I did not use a blacklist in *Jersey 1.x* but with upgrade to 2.x i want to use it.

I've searched the official site, googled the issue about creating a blacklist operation but didn't satisfy with the information.

I intend to create a filter bean which gets the blacklist values from the list in the *root-context.xml*.

I gave a try to PreMatchingFilter class which overrides `filter`method but it seems that i can not reach to that filter.

Here is the PreMatchingFilter class that i implemented.

```
public class PreMatchingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{

    InjectionFilter injectionFilter;
    private final int OK = 200;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        Request requestMajestic = requestContext.getRequest();
        HttpServletRequest requestHttpServlet = (HttpServletRequest) requestMajestic;
        Response responseFilterized = injectionFilter.doFilter(requestHttpServlet);
// injectionFilter.doFilter method gets the HttpServletRequest object and searches for //the blacklist values and if they exist returns a response with the status 400, //otherwise 200.
        if( OK != responseFilterized.getStatus())
            requestContext.abortWith(responseFilterized);
    }

    public InjectionFilter getInjectionFilter() {
        return injectionFilter;
    }

    public void setInjectionFilter(InjectionFilter injectionFilter) {
        this.injectionFilter = injectionFilter;
    }
}
```

I know that PreMatchingFilter class filters the request before the request matching is started.

This is my web.xml_ and PreMatchingFilter class is in the package `com.cihan.service.foo`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
        and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters  -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>  

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RestWithJersey2</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.cihan.service.foo</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RestWithJersey2</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/jersey2/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- JNDI DATA SOURCE -->
    <resource-ref>
        <description>Oracle Datasource</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/INVEX</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
    <!-- JNDI DATA SOURCE -->
</web-app>
```

So, is there anything wrong with the Jersey2 configuration or is there another way to create a blacklist in Jersey2?

Comment: Do you have `@Provider` annotation on the filter?

Comment: No sir, i'll give it a try. By the way, is my approach to create blacklist appropriate? Is it really the best way to make a blacklist in my way?

Comment: @Provider makes the class useable anymore. Thanks, but i am still wondering how to build a blacklist structure within Jersey2.